# cloudify 2.7, I want to use cloudify pre-install jdk 1.7 for my application

Tags: cloudify

I am using cloudify 2.7, the byon.xml config jdk is 1.6 bin, but now, my application need jdk 1.7, so I want to download jdk 1.7 bin version, but I did not find it, so I config jdk 1.7 gz and tar version in byon.xml, but cloudify agent can not install it.
I read cloudify document write:
/* 
The following optional attribute contains the path from which the JDK will be downloaded. Default Linux values are : 32 bit 
http: //repository.cloudifysource.org/com/oracle/java/1.6.0_32/jdk-6u32-linux-i586.bin 64 bit
http: //repository.cloudifysource.org/com/oracle/java/1.6.0_32/jdk-6u32-linux-x64.bin
 But you can set it manually as follows :
(If you want to rely on the pre-installed JDK, set javaUrl to "NO_INSTALL")
 */ 
javaUrl "http: //my-pc:8080/java.bin"

**so my question is how can I use cloudify pre-install jdk 1.7?**

Answer (score 1):

Cloudify uses Oracle JDK 6, though it should work using any compatible JDK.

As this is the JDK that Cloudify was tested with, I recommend that you keep using JDK 6 to run Cloudify, and install JDK 1.7 separately for your application. Cloudify does not install JDK 6 at the system level - it is not installed as a system package (like apt or yum) - it is just a tar/zip that is uncompressed. So you can simply have a preInstall lifecycle script that installs JDK 7, either at the system level or the user level.

Once JDK 7 is installed, you will probably need to edit your start script to add the JAVA_HOME environment variable and add the bin directory of JDK 7 to the PATH environment variable. This will not interfere with Cloudify's agent.